# How to search for keyword in three different tables

Tags: php, mysql

Good day, i have been trying to do a simple search from three tables, how posdible is that.
I have tables like

- Songs
- Videos
- Posts

The songs table has columns like song_title,song_author.
The videos table has columns like videos_title,videos_author.
While the posts table also have post_title, post_author.

But i want to search a keyword from a search  input box in these columns
"Song_title,song_author,video_title,video_,author,post_title"

What i tried so far seems to be completely useless which is:

```
    $query = "(SELECT song_title, song_author, 'song' as type FROM songs WHERE song_title LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' OR song_author LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%')
 UNION
 (SELECT video_title, video_author, 'video' as type FROM videos WHERE video_title LIKE '%" . $keyword . "%' OR video_author LIKE '%" . $keyword ."%') 
UNION
 (SELECT post_title,'post' as type FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%"')"; 


mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: You are missing the end of the `LIKE` condition in the last UNIONed query : `FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%"'` should be `FROM posts WHERE post_title LIKE '%". $keyword . "%'`

Comment: The number of columns for two `UNION` operands must be the same. And their type have to be compatible. I assume the title columns have the same type in all tables and so do the author columns. But in your last subquery the columns are only two. You should insert `post_author` there too. You should also use `UNION ALL`  instead of `UNION`. `UNION` remove duplicates, which probably not what you want nor need.

Comment: Must i have the same columns or the same number of colums. I dont get...if i add post_author will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL query you're possible looking for is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT song_title AS title, song_author AS author, 'song' as type FROM songs
UNION
SELECT video_title AS title, video_author AS author, 'video' as type FROM videos
UNION
SELECT post_title AS title, NULL AS author, 'post' as type FROM posts) a
WHERE title LIKE '%'.$keyword.'%' OR author LIKE '%'.$keyword.'%'
```

Also, please consider two more important notes:

1. It is VERY unsafe to use something like '%'.$keyword.'%' in queries. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
2. You might want to retrieve some kind of ids from your tables, to use further.

Comment: Thank you, but how do i fetch the resultset indicating data from specific table